# Windows Store App XAML: Gridview doesn't show image on full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, windows-8

A few days ago I started to develop a Windows Store App using C#/XAML. In my App I want to show GridView with images, but first image must be showed on full screen (for example, if user have screen 1920x1080px, first GridView item must be 1920x1080px).

I have the next trouble: When I add first item, GridView cuts image at the bottom.
To prove it, I prepared image 1920x1080px (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhCfi.png) with Red line on border (it's 1.png in XAML). As you can see on screenshot of my app https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMLg1.png, red line there is at top, left and right, but at  the bottom line is missing and black background is visible.

It's my XAML code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyle1" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <GridViewItemPresenter CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}"
                                           CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}"
                                           ContentMargin="0"
                                           ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                           CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}"
                                           DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                           DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                                           DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                           FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                           Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                           PointerOverBackgroundMargin="0"
                                           PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                           SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"
                                           SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                                           SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                           SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           SelectedBorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"
                                           SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="Assets/1.png" Width="1920" Height="1080"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way to solve this problem. All what we need, it set Padding="0" in GridView.
This is the code which solved my problem:

```
<GridView Padding="0" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="Assets/1.png" Width="1920" Height="1080"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when you change the bottom margin in your `GridViewItemStyle1` to -12, then it works.

```
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-12"/>
```

12 is probably the default space between items. Some time ago I was reading Windows Phone 7 design guidelines and there was mentioned that 12 is a *magic number* for margins and sizes.

Comment: Your solution works, but it doesn't works correctly when i'm trying to choose the item. When I have more than one item in my GridView and i'm trying to choose one of them, I see that they overlap each other, because we use <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-12"/> in GridViewItemStyle1.